# Python property magic

Tags: python

When is the `inner()` function actually getting called in this simple code snippet?
I have read about python properties, but I am unsure what magic is it doing here.

```
>>> class Magic:
...     @property
...     def __repr__(self):
...         def inner():
...             return "It works!"
...         return inner
...
>>> repr(Magic())
'It works!'
```

When I remove `"@property"`, I get an expected error:

```
TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type function)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) is supposed to give a human-readable representation of the object...

> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object.
>
> For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval(), otherwise **the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object**. A class can control what this function returns for its instances by defining a __repr__() method.

You are returning a function.
Try:

```
>>> class Magic:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         def inner():
...             return "It works!"
...         return inner()
...
>>> repr(Magic())
'It works!'
```

---

It's also worth reading up on the `@property` decorator, and decorators in general... See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330273/1347519).

---

To answer youy "*When is the inner() function actually getting called?*", see below. It's getting called when `repr()` calls `Magic.__repr__()` on your behalf.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def my_decorator(info):
    def my_dec_inner(self):
        return "Testing"
    return my_dec_inner

class Magic:
    @my_decorator
    def __repr__(self):
        def inner():
            return "It works!"
        return inner

m = Magic()

# these are nearly synonymous
print(m.__repr__())
print(repr(m))

# this is actually a 'bound function' - my_decorator
print(m.__repr__)
```

```
Testing
Testing
<bound method Magic.my_dec_inner of Testing>
```

Comment: Thanks Attie. I get it now.